# Problem converting documentSnapshot to custom object

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I've been trying to download a custom object from Firestore after uploading it, the Document does have the info but it doesn't convert it to the custom object and getting single values from the document doesn't work either. I get every field of my custom object as null beside one integer that gets 0 although it shouldn't be equal 0.
Code for downloading:

```
 DocumentReference docRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection(email).document(flightName);
    docRef.get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
            Flight flight = documentSnapshot.toObject(Flight.class);
            flightArrayList.add(flight);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(myadapter);
        }
    });
```

code for my class Flight:

```
private String name, email;
private int countPictures;
private String dateStart, dateEnd;
private ArrayList<String> links;

 public Flight() {

}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public int getCountPictures() {
    return countPictures;
}

public void setCountPictures(int countPictures) {
    this.countPictures = countPictures;
}

public String getDateStart() {
    return dateStart;
}

public void setDateStart(String dateStart) {
    this.dateStart = dateStart;
}

public String getDateEnd() {
    return dateEnd;
}

public void setDateEnd(String dateEnd) {
    this.dateEnd = dateEnd;
}

public ArrayList<String> getLinks() {
    return links;
}

public void setLinks(ArrayList<String> links) {
    this.links = links;
}
```

Upload Code:

```
    DocumentReference docRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection(flight.getEmail()).document(flight.getName());
    Map<String, Object> flightObject = new HashMap<>();
    flightObject.put("FLIGHT", flight);
    docRef.set(flightObject)
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                    Toast.makeText(SaveAct.this, "saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            })
            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(SaveAct.this, "error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            });
```

Firestore screen:
[image]

document content from the debugger:

```
Document{key=yuvala2001@gmail.com/night test, data=ArraySortedMap{(FLIGHT=>ArraySortedMap{(countPictures=>2), (dateEnd=>2019-03-12 19:30), (dateStart=>2019-03-12 19:30), (email=>yuvala2001@gmail.com), (links=>[https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/gsdemo-3f97f.appspot.com/o/yuvala2001%40gmail.com%2Fnight%20test_0?alt=media&token=7242371e-a853-48d7-adab-05795493c352, https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/gsdemo-3f97f.appspot.com/o/yuvala2001%40gmail.com%2Fnight%20test_1?alt=media&token=b249ea0a-55bb-46e0-b8b0-f8f1c065c613]), (name=>night test)};)};, version=SnapshotVersion(seconds=1552411921, nanos=640212000), documentState=SYNCED}
```

### **Edit:**

I have fixed the code, problem was uploading the object inside the map, according to Firebase docs this won't upload it correctly for you to download.
Correct code for upload:

```
DocumentReference docRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection(flight.getEmail()).document(flight.getName());
    docRef.set(flight)
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                    Toast.makeText(SaveAct.this, "saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            })
            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(SaveAct.this, "error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            });
```

Comment: Please show the exact contents of the document you are trying to convert, and also how you expect its fields to be mapped into a Flight object.  Also please show the entire Flight class, don't cut out the getters and setters, as their names do matter.

Comment: @DougStevenson I have edited my question with the getters, setters and a screen shot from the firestore screen. the names of the variables are the same names in the custom object and the firestore

Comment: @DougStevenson As I wrote, all my fields are getting null beside countPictures that gets 0 as a value, the info from the firestore suppose to be there instead. And no errors appeared in the logcat about it from what I noticed

Comment: Does the requested document actually exist?  Check the exists method on the snapshot object.  We have no guarantee that what you're requesting is what you've shown here.

Comment: @DougStevenson I checked using a breakpoint, I could get both documents but the info couldn't be converted from document to Flight object

Comment: Please also add the code that you are using to add data to the database and please also responde with @AlexMamo Can you also please print the content of your `documentsnapshot` and add it to your question?

Comment: @AlexMamo I have added the code for the uploading and got the content from the debugger using a breakpoint

Comment: @AlexMamo I noticed that I get this line in the logcat: [CustomClassMapper]: No setter/field for Flight found on class com.dji.GSDemo.GoogleMap.Flight

Comment: Do you have any field property for `Flight`?

Comment: @AlexMamo What do you mean?

Comment: Do you have anywhere in your code(model class) a Flight property?

Comment: @AlexMamo I do have a different file for the Flight object, it's code is already included

Comment: @AlexMamo managed to fix my code, problem was uploading the Flight object inside the map, it should have been uploaded as it is. I have edited the post with the correct code